# Add additional text to string

Tags: r

How do I add the additional text `p=` before the values in the data frame?
Do you use gsub?

```
> pvaluesmir21
   Seqbuster_Filter_MM_miR21_5p$FDR
1                      8.326135e-02
2                      6.336574e-05
3                      3.233019e-17
4                      4.800951e-22
5                      3.054728e-10
6                      6.697357e-11
```

Answer (score 3):

It is more natural to use `paste` or `sprintf`

```
 pvaluemir21[,1] <- paste('p =', pvaluemir21[,1])
```

Or

```
 pvaluemir21[,1] <- sprintf('p = %f', pvaluemir21[,1])
```

But `sub` can be used

```
 pvaluemir21[,1] <- sub('(.*)', 'p=\\1', pvaluesmir21[,1])
```